# Isn't it illegal C# code to jump into a label inside a loop from outside the loop?

Tags: c#, .net

At about 09:19 in [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Charles/Jeffrey-Richter-and-his-AsyncEnumerator) on Channel 9 where Jeffrey Richter demonstrates his `AsyncEnumerator` to Charlie Calvert, he shows a piece of code where the flow-of-control jumps to a label inside a `while` loop obeying a `goto` instruction that is outside the loop. That blew me away. I was in disbelief for a moment.

So, I tried something similar, and as I expected, C# does not let me do that because the label is not in the block scope of the `goto` statement from where I want to jump.

```
using System;

namespace JumpToInsideALoopWithGoToTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static int i = 0;
        static int someRandomNumber = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static bool GoToInsideLoopTest(int howMany)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                i = 1; return true;
            }

            if (i == 1)
            {
                while (someRandomNumber < howMany)
                {
                    i = 2;
                    return true;

                    Increment: i++;
                }
            }

            if (i == 2)
            {
                goto Increment;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

What then? I don't even know what my question here is. Like, what was that I saw then?

I am suspecting the code he showed was pseudo code? Or may be such a thing is possible in IL? At any rate, what was that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe he was demonstrating the state machine that the C# compiler generates for async and iterator methods. The compiler does not need to adhere to C# syntax requirements. All it needs to do is make the CLR happy.

At the CLR level all local variables are declared at the top of the function so to speak. They are available everywhere. There are not declaration issues and no issues with uninitialized variables.

The CLR imposes its own requirements which mostly are about the execution stack being properly formed. This is not an issue when jumping to locations where the stack is empty such as between statements. Since `await` can appear within expressions there is a rewrite that rewires everything so that the state machine jumps are to locations with empty stack.

For the C# compiler it's not a problem to jump to pretty much any place.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have been through the compiler generated state machine code for the iterator many times over the years and am fairly familiar with it. Just this bit confused me. Thanks for sorting it out.

Comment: Heheh! Thank you. :-)

Comment: But if look at IL code of real MoveNext of iterator he mentiones in a video - there seems to be no gotos and no loops even, just one switch statement. So it seems equaly probable that it's just kind of pseudo-code to simplify complex logic, not?

Comment: I admit I never inspected the IL. I'll take a look. Maybe it's a "duffs device" where they `switch` based on the state of the iterator?

Comment: Yes, it's a `switch`: http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:>il/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsB0BhA9gG31QGNkxcIRMBxVCVAJzGIG4AoAB2ACN9mZi+AIYgQMbDADebGLJhde/FELLEYASQCiEYOkZDeqADyRkAPhgBZABQBKKTLlOEYVPgAmMBqmTAGEGABGdidnVw8vHz8AgCYQuQBfNgSgA==

Comment: So it's a simple switch without any loops or jumps or unrolling of loops, and then his code looks not like real compiler output but more a pseudo code?

Comment: @Evk Thanks very much.

Comment: @Evk: I note that the real codegen is considerably more complex in a number of interesting cases. For example, when you need to `goto` into the middle of a statement, when you need to `goto` into a finally block, and so on. There are *plenty* of situations where the compiler needs to generate code that would look exceedingly odd if decompiled back to C#. Treat any description of the actual control flow of an async method as pseudocode that just gets the idea across; the reality is often more complex, but not more interesting.

Comment: @EricLippert that is true, but in this concrete case we argue if simple iterator method (provided in video, one for loop and couple of yields) could have been converted by compiler to what we see in the next slide. It seems real output for this concrete method is simple and does not contain loops and jumps (while in general that is not always the case as you said).

Comment: Thank you, @EricLippert. I am actually in the middle of importing back the compiler generated state machine for an `await` into a C# program and changing all the illegal identifiers back to legal ones to see what it is doing. I am hoping there will be stuff that isn't valid C# but it will be interesting to watch. :-)

Comment: It turns out that in this instance, i.e. for the transformation that is applied to an `await` keyword in C#, the code produced is legal C# code. I tried it here. Here is the original program: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hEQ0RN and here is the transformation, which I changed the identifier names of to legal C# identifier names: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EHgXgD

Comment: And of course, by *this* instance, I meant the state machine generated for the `await` keyword and not for the `yield return` statement or the `IEnumerator<T>`, which is what Jeffrey is talking about in that video.